# Composer installing irrelevant libraries

Tags: php, composer-php

When I try to `composer require something/something` in my vendor folder
it starts installing a lot of stuff I didn't ask for.

Like I just did `composer require ramsey/uuid`, and Composer created a subfolder called vendor then started downloading a lot of libraries e.g Laravel, Symfony, and Twig (these are just the ones I know).

This first happened when I tried to require Twig. I just deleted the irrelevant libraries and kept Twig.

Does anyone have an idea to whats causing this?

Comment: Whats in your `composer.json` file

Comment: {
    "require": {
        "laravel/laravel": "^5.3"
    }
} i didn't even install laravel

Comment: Remove that line and try again. How did you generate the file in the first place

Comment: I did require twig, but twig is not there as you can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If composer is downloading and installing stuff you didn't ask for, then that stuff probably *was* asked for by one of the following:

- some **require** statement defined in the composer.json file
- a dependency required by something you are installing. I'm not familiar with twig, but it might require laravel, symfony et. al. If you plan to use one of these frameworks, I suggest you install that first before requiring twig.
- some cached thing somewhere, like the composer.lock file mentioned above

Composer creates the folder called vendor as the home for all of the libraries/packages that it fetches and installs.

Answer (score 2):

You can always check, why Composer installed something, by runnung

```
$ composer why webmozart/assert
```

The command will show you, which of the root requirements depends on the package (`webmozart/assert` in this case).

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to delete everything and start from scratch, given that you haven't really done much yet (as you say, your `composer.json` file is empty):

```
$ rm -rf vendor/
$ rm composer.json
$ rm composer.lock
```

Then, start composer and install the dependency again:

```
$ composer init
$ composer require ramsey/uuid
```

You should now have it all working.

My assumption is that you were running `composer install` based on an older `composer.lock` file, which will re-download the dependencies.